# In Excel, how can I plot data based on user inputting number of rows?

Tags: excel, input, plot, rows

Prefer not to use VBA if I can help it. I have 1000 rows x 2 columns of data. In cell B2, I (or user) would enter 600 for example and would like the scatter plot that already exists in the worksheet to plot just the first 600 rows x 2 columns. Change B2 to 200 and plot just those first 200 rows, etc... Thanks for any assistance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learnt this off Mr. Peltier. You can look up dynamic charts.

But basically this will give you the first n rows. For this n is in D2 as I used A & B as my chart range.

Define two named ranges.

chtrng:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,MIN(Sheet1!$D$2,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A)-1),1)
```

chtvals:

```
=OFFSET(chtrng,0,1)
```

Then pick a cell and insert scatter chart.
Add a series.

xvalues =

```
=Sheet1!chtrng
```

yvalues=

```
=Sheet1!chtvals
```

Now it should change rows plotted when you change D2.

Comment: Thank you very much. This did the trick. I would upvote it if I could. I learned something new today in Excel... :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. The reputation requirement is a bugger. Maybe it will allow you to mark it as the answer?